# A cleaner way of getting accented math symbols in LuaLateX

Tags: math-mode, luatex, unicode-math, accents, vscode

Lualatex + unicode-math is awesome, but I'd like to be able to type $Â$ (in `vscode`) to get the same as if I were to type $\hat A$. So I wrote the clunky code below which does exactly what I want it to do, but there has to be a cleaner / less costly way of achieving the same thing?  When I say costly, I mean that it searches the line for each of the characters and then just steps through, changing the input.

Pointers on how my *LuaLaTeX* code can be improved?  I'm looking for a lualatex only solution.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}  % for the weird accents


\directlua{
    
    function fixline( line, nm, str, ch )
        beg,fin = unicode.utf8.find( line, ch )
        if beg == nil then return line end
        lastp = 0
        lastc = 0
        nline = ""
        for p,c in utf8.codes( line ) do
            if c == nm then
                if lastc == 0 then
                else
                    nline = nline..str..utf8.char( lastc )
                end
                lastc = 0
            else
                if lastc == 0 then
                else
                    nline = nline..utf8.char( lastc )
                end
                lastc = c
            end
            lastp = p
        end
        if lastc == 0 then
            else
            nline = nline..utf8.char( lastc )
        end
        return nline
    end

    function ParseMe( line )
        line = fixline( line, 770, "\\hat ", "̂" )
        line = fixline( line, 771, "\\tilde ", "̃" )
        line = fixline( line, 772, "\\bar ", "̄" )
        line = fixline( line, 773, "\\tilde ", "̃" )
        line = fixline( line, 774, "\\breve ", "̆" )
        line = fixline( line, 775, "\\dot ", "̇" )
        line = fixline( line, 776, "\\ddot ", "̈" )
        line = fixline( line, 778, "\\ocirc ", "̊" )
        line = fixline( line, 780, "\\check ", "̌" )
        line = fixline( line, 768, "\\grave ", "̀" )
        line = fixline( line, 769, "\\acute ", "́" )
        line = fixline( line, 8407, "\\vec ", "⃗" )
        line = fixline( line, 8411, "\\dddot ", "⃛" )
        line = fixline( line, 777, "\\ovhook ", "̉" )
        line = fixline( line, 786, "\\oturnedcomma ", "̒" )
        line = fixline( line, 784, "\\candra ", "̐" )
        line = fixline( line, 8406, "\\overleftarrow ", "⃖" )
        line = fixline( line, 8432, "\\asteraccent ", "⃰" )
        line = fixline( line, 8423, "\\annuity ", "⃧" )
        line = fixline( line, 8417, "\\overleftrightarrow ", "⃡" )
        line = fixline( line, 8401, "\\rightharpoonaccent ", "⃑" )
        line = fixline( line, 8400, "\\leftharpoonaccent ", "⃐" )
        line = fixline( line, 794, "\\droang ", "̚" )
        line = fixline( line, 789, "\\ocommatopright ", "̕" )
        line = fixline( line, 8425, "\\widebridgeabove ", "⃩" )
        return line
    end

    id,error = luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", ParseMe, "Beautiful Accents" )
}



\begin{document}

\[ 
  Ã,Â,Ă,Ā,Ȧ,Ä,Å,Ǎ,A⃗,À,Á,A⃛,Ả,A⃖,A̐,A⃰,A̒,A̕,A̚,A⃐,A⃑,A⃡,A⃧,A⃩,Â
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may not need lua for this: see egreg’s answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144347/accents-and-unicode-math). See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77596/is-direct-utf8-input-of-combining-diacritics-in-math-mode-possible-with-lualatex) on combining accents and math mode.

Comment: Thank you @renkema.  No, my code above gives me the behavior that I want.  I'm just looking for a way to streamline it.  The post in your link does more or less the same thing  without using lualatex, which I suppose is an advantage, but using tex macros makes it even clunkier than what I have.  I was hoping for a method that streamlined the lua code that I already have.

Comment: You might want to look at the code at the end of my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456225/80496

Comment: Thanks @MarcelKrüger.  I'll have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that using the `pre_mlist_to_hlist_filter` callback to operate on the nodes directly is much cleaner than doing textual replacements inside `process_input_buffer`, but it's also much more complicated:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\csname@mathmargin\endcsname=0pt


\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
    -- Save local versions of some frequently-used globals
    local combining_classes = require("luaotfload-unicode").ccc
    local fields = node.fields
    local get_font = font.getfont
    local ipairs = ipairs
    local is_node = node.is_node
    local new_node = node.new
    local slide = node.slide


    -- Define some constants
    local ACCENT = 200 -- Something with a “Canonical Combining Class Value”
                       -- ≥ 200 is probably an accent
    local accent_id = node.id("accent")
    local BAD_FIELDS = {
        id = true,
        next = true,
        prev = true,
        subtype = true,
    }
    local mathchar_id = node.id("math_char")
    local noad_id = node.id("noad")


    -- The main function
    local function fix_accents(head)
        -- Loop through all the nodes
        local n = head
        repeat
            -- Recurse
            for _, field in ipairs(fields(n.id)) do
                if is_node(n[field]) and field ~= "attr" then
                    n[field] = fix_accents(n[field])
                end
            end

            -- See if the current node is an accent character typeset as a
            -- regular math character
            if n.id == noad_id and
               n.nucleus and
               n.nucleus.id == mathchar_id and
               (combining_classes[n.nucleus.char] or 0) >= ACCENT
            then
                -- Get the accent and the preceding character (its base)
                local accent = n
                local base = n.prev

                -- Create a new “accent” node
                local new = new_node(accent_id)

                -- Copy over all the fields
                for _, field in ipairs(fields(accent.id)) do
                    if not BAD_FIELDS[field] and accent[field] then
                        new[field] = accent[field]
                    end
                end
                for _, field in ipairs(fields(base.id)) do
                    if not BAD_FIELDS[field] and base[field] then
                        new[field] = base[field]
                    end
                end

                -- Set the new nucleus and accent fields
                new.nucleus = base.nucleus
                new.accent = accent.nucleus

                -- Get the fonts used for the accent and the base
                local accent_font = get_font(accent.nucleus.font)
                local base_font = get_font(base.nucleus.font)

                -- If the accent isn't available in its original font, check
                -- if it's in the base glyph's font
                if not accent_font.characters[accent.nucleus.char] and
                   base_font.characters[accent.nucleus.char]
                then
                    -- Use the base glyph's font
                    new.accent.fam = new.nucleus.fam
                end

                -- Replace the accent and base nodes with the new “accent” node
                if base.prev then
                    base.prev.next = new
                else
                    head = new
                end
                new.next = accent.next
                n = new
                slide(head)
            end

            n = n.next
        until not n

        return head
    end


    -- Define the callback
    luatexbase.add_to_callback(
        "pre_mlist_to_hlist_filter",
        fix_accents,
        "fix_accents"
    )
\end{luacode*}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{8em}p{6em}}
        All the accents:
        \begin{equation*}
            \begin{array}{*5c}
                Ã  &  Â  &  Ă  &  Ā  &  Ȧ  \\
                Ä  &  Å  &  Ǎ  &  A⃗  &  À  \\
                Á  &  A⃛  &  Ả  &  A⃖  &  A̐  \\
                A⃰  &  A̒  &  A̕  &  A̚  &  A⃐  \\
                A⃑  &  A⃡  &  A⃧  &  A⃩  &  Ẫ
            \end{array}
        \end{equation*}

        &

        Nested:
        \begin{equation*}
            \sqrt[A̚]{Â^{\frac{Ã}{Å_{A⃰^{Ä}}}}}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!